# Javascript Slotmachine naming images

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to make a very basic slot machine game in JavaScript. I managed to get the slots moving and stop on random images, with a alert box appearing informing whether there is a match, a trio or nothing at all, but I cant figure out how to change the code in a way that when the slots stop my alert box will display the message of game status (2 Matches/ All three match/ no matches) as well as on what image the slot stopped e.g. (Two Matches - Banana, Cherry, Banana) (Its a Trio - Lemon, Lemon, Lemon) or (No Match - Cherry, Banana, Lemon)

```js
var slotitem = [];
slotitem[0] = "Banana";
slotitem[1] = "Bar";
slotitem[2] = "BigWin";

function rollem() {
  counter = 0;
  spinem();
}

function spinem() {
  turns1 = 3 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
  for (a = 0; a < turns1; a++) {
    document.slots.slot1.src = "" + slotitem[a % 3] + ".jpg";
  }
  turns2 = 3 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
  for (b = 0; b < turns2; b++) {
    document.slots.slot2.src = "" + slotitem[b % 3] + ".jpg";
  }
  turns3 = 3 + Math.floor((Math.random() * 3))
  for (c = 0; c < turns3; c++) {
    document.slots.slot3.src = "" + slotitem[c % 3] + ".jpg";
  }
  counter++;
  console.log(counter);
  if (counter < 25) {
    setTimeout("spinem(counter);", 50);
  } else {
    checkmatch();
  }
}

function checkmatch() {
  if ((document.slots.slot1.src == document.slots.slot2.src) && (document.slots.slot1.src == document.slots.slot3.src)) {
    alert("Trio! You WIN!")
  } else if ((document.slots.slot1.src + slotitem == 0 == document.slots.slot2.src + slotitem == 0) 
             || (document.slots.slot1.src + slotitem == 0 == document.slots.slot3.src + slotitem == 0) 
             || (document.slots.slot2.src + slotitem == 0 == document.slots.slot3.src + slotitem == 0)) {
    alert("Bannananana")
  } else if ((document.slots.slot1.src + slotitem == 1 == document.slots.slot2.src + slotitem == 1) 
             || (document.slots.slot1.src + slotitem == 1 == document.slots.slot3.src + slotitem == 1) 
             || (document.slots.slot2.src + slotitem == 1 == document.slots.slot3.src + slotitem == 1)) {
    alert("Barrrr")
  } else if ((document.slots.slot1.src + slotitem == 2 == document.slots.slot2.src + slotitem == 2) 
             || (document.slots.slot1.src + slotitem == 2 == document.slots.slot3.src + slotitem == 2) 
             || (document.slots.slot2.src + slotitem == 2 == +document.slots.slot3.src + slotitem == 2)) {
    alert("Big Wim")
  } else if ((document.slots.slot1.src != document.slots.slot2.src) && (document.slots.slot1.src != document.slots.slot3.src)) {
    alert("All Different - You Lose!")
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Dice Game</title>
  <script src="slotMachine.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form name=slots onsubmit="rollem(); return false;">
    <table border=0 cellpadding=3 cellspacing=1 width=300>
      <tr>
        <th colspan=2>Welcome to the Slot Machine!</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
          <hr> </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan=2>
          <center>
            <table cellspacing=5 cellpadding=2 border=0>
              <tr>
                <td> <img src=Banana.jpg name=slot1> </td>
                <td> <img src=Orange.jpg name=slot2> </td>
                <td> <img src=Melon.jpg name=slot3> </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
            <tr>
              <th> <input type=submit value="Spin the slots"> </th>
              <!<input type=text readonly size=33 name=banner></td>
        </tr>
  </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Is there any other code in your project?

Comment: No this is it. I mean this is a shorten down version to only three images, in the full version it goes up to 8, so the only difference would be in the array size, and matter of changing some numbers in spinem() function